# Can Linux do "source MAC based routing?"

Tags: linux, networking, routing, mac-address, source-routing

I'm looking for a way in Linux to perform source-MAC based routing.

My goal is to have a router with the following routing:

```
echo 100 inbound >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add iif eth0 priority 100 table inbound
ip route add default via <myproxy> dev eth1 table inbound

echo 200 returntosender >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add iif eth1 priority 200 table returntosender
*use source MAC from the initial packet to find the next-hop through dev eth0*
```

The packets hitting my router on eth0 will be sent out on eth1 to a transparent proxy that does not modify the Layer 3 or 4 source/destination, and the proxy will send the packets back to eth1.  The router then needs to decide where to forward the packets, which should be based on the source MAC from where it received the initial packet on eth0.

Does Linux have a way to do this?  I'm fine with using quagga/VyOS/frr or anything that will accomplish this.  I just haven't found a "MAC-flipping"/"return-to-sender"/"symmetric-return" mechanism in Linux yet.  Apparently some proprietary products have it: https://www.kareemccie.com/2019/12/what-is-source-mac-address-based-routing.html

**EDIT**

```
192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1)
198.51.100.0/25 (TEST-NET-2a)
198.51.100.128/25 (TEST-NET-2b)
203.0.113.0/25 (TEST-NET-3a)
203.0.113.128/25 (TEST-NET-3b)

client: 192.0.2.100/24 (TEST-NET-1)
routerA1: 192.0.2.1/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.1/25 (TEST-NET-2a), and 203.0.113.1/24 (TEST-NET-3a)
routerA2: 192.0.2.2/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.2/25 (TEST-NET-2a), and 203.0.113.2/24 (TEST-NET-3a)
routerAN: 192.0.2.N/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.N/25 (TEST-NET-2a), and 203.0.113.N/24 (TEST-NET-3a) for 1<=N<=50
myrouter: 198.51.100.100/25 (TEST-NET-2a), 198.51.100.129/25 (TEST-NET-2b)
myproxy: 198.51.100.200/25 (TEST-NET-2b)
server: 203.0.113.222/25 (TEST-NET-3b)

L2 SRC | Client MAC     | RA1 MAC       | MyR MAC        | MyPrxy MAC     | MyR MAC        | RA1 MAC      
L2 DST | RA1 MAC        | MyR MAC       | MyPrxy MAC     | MyR MAC        | RA1 MAC        | NextHop MAC    
L3 SRC | 192.0.2.100    | 192.0.2.100   | 192.0.2.100*   | 192.0.2.100*   | 192.0.2.100    | 192.0.2.100  
L3 DST | 203.0.113.222  | 203.0.113.222 | 203.0.113.222* | 203.0.113.222* | 203.0.113.222  | 203.0.113.222
L4 SRC | 35555 (client) | 35555         | 35555*         | 35555*         | 35555          | 35555        
L4 DST | 80 (server)    | 80            | 80*            | 80*            | 80             | 80           
(* means maintaining L3/L4 at this point in the flow is not critical)

client      ->     routerA1     ->    myrouter   ->  myproxy   ->   myrouter   ->   routerA1      ->      server
       (TEST-NET-1)       (TEST-NET-2a)    (TEST-NET-2b)   (TEST-NET-2b)   (TEST-NET-2a)   (TEST-NET-3a,TEST-NET-3b)
```

When `myrouter` receives packets from `routerA1`, it will not see the L3 address of routerA1, but only the L3 address of the client and server.  `myproxy` will do some processing on the packets and return the processed packets to `myrouter`, which has to return the packets to routerA1.  There are multiple instances of `routerA` and the correct instance has to be used for the egress traffic, but the only way to identify which instance sent `myrouter` a packet is by the source MAC address.

routerA is a black-box in this example.  It will handle seeing the same packet twice as the packets go from client to server, and twice as the packets return from server to client.  I.e. it will not continually loop ingress packets back to myrouter.

To keep  things simple, myproxy is just another router with a default gateway of myrouter.  I.e. anything that hits myproxy will return to myrouter.  myrouter then has to send the packets back to the correct instance of routerA based on the source MAC of the ingress packet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135306/discussion-on-question-by-rusty-lemur-can-linux-do-source-mac-based-routing).